# Inbound Change Set, Apex Classes Fail

Tags: apex, apexrest

I'm pushing apex classes code from sandbox to production, but when needed to make deploy, apex class fail.

I don't have an apex test .

My code :

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/agln/*')
global class AglnController {

    private static final Integer PAGE_LIMIT = 20;
    private static list<String> parameters;
    private static list<String> keywordParameters;
    private static String baseQuery = 'select Name, Profile_Picture_URL__c, Title_and_Org__c, Primary_Engagement_Program__c,' +
                                              'Primary_Engagement_Class__c, Primary_Affiliation_Type__c, Email, MobilePhone,' +
                                              'HomePhone, Primary_Assistant_Name__c, Primary_Assistant_Email__c,Bio__c,' +
                                              'City_State_Country__c from contact';

    global static Integer getPageOffset(){
        if(! String.isEmpty(RestContext.request.params.get('page'))){
            return Integer.valueOf(RestContext.request.params.get('page')) * PAGE_LIMIT;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    global static void buildWhereCondition(String key, boolean isLike) {
        if(String.isEmpty(RestContext.request.params.get(key))){
            return;
        }

        String value = RestContext.request.params.get(key);
        if (!isLike){
            parameters.add(' ' + key + ' =\'' + value + '\'');
        }else{
            parameters.add(' ' + key + ' like \'%' + value + '%\'');
        } 
    }

    global static void buildKeywordCondition(String keyword){
         keywordParameters.add(' FirstName' + ' like \'%' + keyword + '%\' ');
         keywordParameters.add(' LastName' + ' like \'%' + keyword + '%\' ');
         keywordParameters.add(' Title' + ' like \'%' + keyword + '%\' ');
         keywordParameters.add(' Primary_Engagement_Program__c' + ' like \'%' + keyword + '%\' ');
         keywordParameters.add(' Title_and_Org__c' + ' like \'%' + keyword + '%\' ');
         keywordParameters.add(' City_State_Country__c' + ' like \'%' + keyword + '%\' ');
    }

    @HttpGet
    global static list<contact> getContacts() {
     parameters = new list<String>();
     keywordParameters = new list<String>();

     if(! String.isEmpty(RestContext.request.params.get('keyword'))){
             buildKeywordCondition(RestContext.request.params.get('keyword'));
             baseQuery +=' where ';
             baseQuery += ' (' + String.join(keywordParameters,' or ') + ')';
     }


     buildWhereCondition('FirstName',false);
     buildWhereCondition('LastName',false);
     buildWhereCondition('Primary_Engagement_Program__c',false);
     buildWhereCondition('City_State_Country__c',true);
     buildWhereCondition('Title_and_Org__c',true);
     buildWhereCondition('Primary_Engagement_Class__c',false);


     if(parameters.size() != 0){
         if(keywordParameters.size() != 0){
             baseQuery += ' and ';
         }
         else{
             baseQuery +=' where ';
         }
          baseQuery += ' (' + String.join(parameters,' and ') + ')';
     }

      baseQuery += '  ORDER BY Name ASC ';
      baseQuery += '  limit ' + String.valueOf(PAGE_LIMIT) + ' offset ' + String.valueOf(getPageOffset());


     List<Contact> contacts = Database.query(baseQuery);
     return contacts;

    }

}
```

error occurred :[image]

Comment: post your error here and have you added test classes to your change set ?

Comment: Update your test class with mandatory field .

Comment: If you are not sure how to write tests, you might consider working your way through some [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/apex_testing) modules.

Answer (score 0):

I have been make This Apex Classes and It Solved Problem ,Thanks for you.

```
@isTest
public class AglnControllerTest {
    @isTest static void allFellows() {
        RestRequest req = new RestRequest();
        req.params.put('page','0');
        RestResponse res = new RestResponse();
        RestContext.response = res;
        RestContext.request = req;
        Test.startTest();
        List<Contact> contacts = AglnController.getContacts();
        Test.stopTest();
        System.assert(contacts.isEmpty() , contacts.isEmpty());
    }

    @isTest static void getFellowsWithSomeKeyword() {
        RestRequest req = new RestRequest();
        req.params.put('keyword','keyword');
        req.params.put('page','0');
        req.params.put('FirstName' ,'sari');
        req.params.put('Primary_Engagement_Program__c' , 'Primary_Engagement_Program__c');
        req.params.put('LastName','LastName');
        req.params.put('Title' ,'Title');
        req.params.put(' Title_and_Org__c','Title_and_Org__c');
        req.params.put(' City_State_Country__c' ,'City_State_Country__c');

        RestResponse res = new RestResponse();
        RestContext.response = res;
        RestContext.request = req;

        Test.startTest();
        List<Contact> contacts = AglnController.getContacts();
        Test.stopTest();

        System.assert(contacts.isEmpty() , contacts.isEmpty());
    }
}
```